# Regular expression to match decimals with or without leading zeros

Tags: regex

```
^([0-9]*[1-9][0-9]*(\.[0-9]+)?|[0]+\.[0-9]*[1-9][0-9]*)$
```

I don't know regular expression well.
Above regular expression does not allow input .2 .but it allows all other decimals like 0.2 , 0.02 etc . I need to make this expression allow the number like .2 ,.06 , etc.....

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just change the `+` after `[0]` into an ansterisk `*":

```
^([0-9]*[1-9][0-9]*(\.[0-9]+)?|[0]*\.[0-9]*[1-9][0-9]*)$
```

So instead of allowing one or more zeroes preceding the dot, just allow 0 or more.

Comment: just planned to post :)
^([0-9]*[1-9][0-9]*(\.[0-9]+)?|[0]*\.[0-9]*[1-9][0-9]*)$

Comment: This is the most relevant. Thank you @Joey

Answer (score 8):

I like this regexp for floating point numbers, its pretty smart in that it wont match `0.0` as a number.  It requires at least one non-zero number on either side of the period.  Figured I'd break it into its parts to provide a deeper understanding of it.

```
^             #Match at start of string
 (            #start capture group
  [0-9]*       # 0-9, zero or more times
  [1-9]        # 1-9
  [0-9]*       # 0-9, zero or more times
  (            #start capture group
   \.           # literal .
   [0-9]+       # 0-9, one or more times
  )?           #end group - make it optional
 |            #OR - If the first option didn't match, try alternate
  [0]+         # 0, one or more times ( change this to 0* for zero or more times )
  \.           # literal .
  [0-9]*       # 0-9, zero or more times
  [1-9]        # 1-9
  [0-9]*       # 0-9, zero or more times
 )            #end capture group
$             #match end of string
```

The regexp has two smaller patterns inside of it, the first matches cases where the number is >= 1 (having at least one non-zero character left of the .) optionally allowing for a period with one or more trailing numbers.  The second matches <1.0 and ensures that there is at least one non-zero digit on the right side of the dot.

Johannes' answer already gives you the `[0]*` solution to the problem.

Couple of regexp shortcuts, you could replace any instance of `[0-9]` with `\d` in most regexp flavors.  Also `[0]` only matches `0` so you might as well just use `0*` instead of `[0]*`.  The final regexp:

```
/^(\d*[1-9]\d*(\.\d+)?|0*\.\d*[1-9]\d*)$/
```

Comment: Nice explanation. Just as a side remark: to prevent leading zeros, delete the first [0-9]*

Answer (score 2):

I would use this:

```
^(?:(?:0|[1-9][0-9]*)(?:\.[0-9]*)?|\.[0-9]+)$
```

This allows number expressions starting with either

- some digits, followed by optional fractional digits, or
- just fractional digits.

Allowed:

```
123
123.
123.45
.12345
```

But not:

```
.
01234
```

Comment: The original regexp supplied wouldn't allow anything that equaled 0 either...  Yours lost that

Answer (score 1):

You may also use a simple expression like:

```
^[-+]?\d*(\.\d+)?$
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace it with:

```
^([0-9]*[1-9][0-9]*(\.[0-9]+)?|[0]*\.[0-9]*[1-9][0-9]*)$
```

or even shorter:

```
^(\d*[1-9]\d*(\.\d+)?|[0]*\.\d*[1-9]\d*)$
```

Answer (score 0):

I have been working on this from quite a while I got a some good expression that works well

```
 [+-]?(?:\d+|\D{0}\.\d+)(?:\.\d+)?
```

It identifies  numbers/decimals with with/without leading 0's.
Here is the demo on [regx101](https://regex101.com/r/LQrptv/1)

Adding demo here in case link do not works

```
import re      
x = "string .001 or -.001 or 1.00 or -1.00 or-213 or 123.132s1 or 012"   
print(re.findall(r"[+-]?(?:\d+|\D{0}\.\d+)(?:\.\d+)?", x))
```

O/P

```
['.001', '-.001', '1.00', '-1.00', '-213', '123.132', '1', '012']
```