# RegExp for numerics with commas (not required) and decimals

Tags: regex

I am new to REGEXP and am working on a vendor product (tool).
I want to be able to enter from `.00` to `99999999999.99` (with or without commas), as well as decimals.

I have this:

```
^\$?(\d{1,3}(\,\d{3})*|(\d+))(\.\d{1,2})?$
```

This works for these:

```
777777    
777777.7    
777,777    
777,777.77
```

It errors correctly for `7.777`, but I want to be able to enter `.7` or `.0`, but I have to put a `0` in front of them (e.g. `0.7` and `0.0`) for those to work.

Is there a way to enter just a decimal with no leading zero?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Regular expression to match decimals with or without leading zeros](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1388668/regular-expression-to-match-decimals-with-or-without-leading-zeros)

Answer (score 0):

`^\$?(\d{1,3}(\,\d{3})*|(\d*))(\.\d{1,2})?$`

Changed the `+` to `*`

Answer (score 0):

^\d{0,11}[.|\,]\d{2}$   will match from .00 to 99999999999.99 and allow "," instead of "."